# Return value of method is modifying an object passed as a method parameter

Tags: c#, oop

I'm in a situation where I am writing a method where the return value directly modifies a class which was used to supply paramaters to the method.

```
Computer.MatchingPassword = PasswordFinder.Find(Computer.Name, PasswordList)
```

Does assigning to a property of a passed parameter like this have any hazards?

Comment: I reworded so people don't see it as opinion-based. Please review the changes

Comment: @BradleyDotNET appreciate the re-wording. thanks

Comment: Thanks for the re-wording.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, your code sample *doesn't* assign to the parameter, since you passed a property of the `Computer` object.

In other words, you *only* gave the function "name", so assigning to a different property of the same object would have no effect.

Now, in the more general case, you are *still* safe. Even passing the whole object, by the time you assign the return value **the method has already completed**. Any changes you make won't do anything.

In other words, the following code is functionally equivalent:

```
string password = PasswordFinder.Find(Computer.Name, PasswordList);
Computer.MatchingPassword = password;
```

Clearly no problems there. This is true even if it was passed by `ref`, as again, the method is totally done with the object, so any changes to it won't matter.

Comment: Leaves the slightly opinion based part of the (original) question open if that is best practise or if `Find` would better fit into the `Computer` class. But i guess without more context its difficult to answer.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Agreed, almost impossible to answer without more context. It also isn't really relevant to the main part of the question ("Is assigning the return value like this bad?")

Comment: That sounds straight forward to me. I appreciate the re-assurance that the code is safe.

Comment: The other thing, potentially of note, is that it is possible that the method returns before it has actually finished dealing with object. Whilst probably not the case with this method, you could imagine a similar method that starts an Async task, returning before the user is logged in (firing an event or something when it completes). In this case, it's possible you could have issues.. Since the task may still be using the Computer object.

Comment: Saying that.. If the method WAS asynchronous, you would probably still expect it to work just fine.

Comment: @DylanWatson The `async/await` pattern is usually safe here, as it doesn't actually spin up a different thread. But yes, you can certainly create a hazard here, it just isn't because you assigned the return value, you had to do something *else* dangerous.